# Switching user with su db2inst1 prints sh-4.4$

Tags: shell, ubuntu, upgrade, su

I am trying to switch from the logged in user account to db2inst1 user account using the following command:

`su db2inst1`

The command is executed without any warnings or errors, but instead of prompting with `db2inst1@host:~$` I see the following prompt:

```
sh-4.4$
```

In the above configuration, no variables or settings are available which are otherwise available if I log in to Ubuntu directly with the db2inst1 user. Also, executing `ls` confirms I am still in the folder of the original user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is you do not use `db2inst1` user environment. to do it you need to execute

```
su - db2inst1
```

You can check in man pages what this dash do